# Callback function with return type

Tags: c++

Method "DataOperation" has to return the value in DataResponse type.

I have a callback function inside my async request-reply "LoadDataReply" in which i am applying some business logic on the reply received and returning to main method (I am not sure about return to callback is a right way or not).

Can you guys help me on how to return the value for the caller of LoadData method.

```
DataResponse DataOperation::LoadData(const RequestType request)
{
DataResponse dataResponse;
messageAssistant.AsyncRequest("LoadDataList", request)
    .OnReply<MyResponseType>("LoadDataListReply", [this, &dataResponse](auto& reply) { dataResponse = this->LoadDataFromResponse(reply); });

return dataResponse;
}

DataResponse DataOperation::LoadDataFromResponse(const MyResponseType& reply)
{
   ///Doing some operation with reply data
   DataResponse dataResponse;
   dataResponse.Data = reply.Data();
   return dataResponse;
}
```

The above code is not compiling.

I am getting compilation error,

```
error C4716: 'DataOperation::LoadData': must return a value
```

**NOTE:-** I have updated my code and is compiling without any issues. But dataResponse object which I am returning from LoadData at end is not having the values updated in LoadDataFromResponse. it has the initial values.

How i can make sure it returns the updated value rather than initial values?

Comment: You don't return any value there?

Comment: I need to return dataResponse to caller of LoadData method.

Comment: @Joe So, `return` it? `LoadData` is non-void function, yet it doesn't have `return` statement, which, in turn, means that the behavior of such program is undefined.

Comment: I suggest augmenting LoadData to accept another parameter of type `DataResponse&`, and then changing `LoadData` to return `void`. Then the lambda passed to `.OnReply` shall also capture the `DataResponse&` and set it equal to the result of `this->LoadDataFromResponse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by using callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use the handlers. You may create Handler (the message list that can be accessed by every thread). Look at pseodocode below:

```
class Handler {
 public:
  Handler();
  // Constructor
  ~Handler();
  // Destructor
  void pushmessage ( DataResponse* p );
  DataResponse* popmessage();
  bool empty();
protected:
  vector<DataResponse*> pool;
  RTTICriticalSection CS;
};

Handler::Handler()
{
  CS = CreateCriticalSection;
}

Handler::~Handler()
{
  DeleteCriticalSection(CS);
}

void Handler::pushmessage ( DataResponse* p )
{
  EnterCriticalSection(CS);
  try {
    pool.push_back(p)
  } catch(...){
    //
  }
  LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
}

DataResponse* Handler::popmessage() {
  DataResponse* dr = null;
  EnterCriticalSection(CS);
  try {
    dr = pool.back();
    pool.pop_back();
  } catch(...){
    //
  }
  LeaveCriticalSection(CS);    
  return dr;
}

bool Handler::empty() {
  bool res = true;
  EnterCriticalSection(CS);
  try {
    res = pool.empty();
  } catch(...){
    //
  }
  LeaveCriticalSection(CS);    
  return res;      
}

DataResponse DataOperation::LoadData(const RequestType request)
{
   messageAssistant.AsyncRequest("LoadDataList", request)
    .OnReply<MyResponseType>("LoadDataListReply", [this](auto& reply) {  this->LoadDataFromResponse(reply); });  
}

/*DataResponse* */ void DataOperation::LoadDataFromResponse(const MyResponseType& reply)
{
   ///Doing some operation with reply data
   DataResponse* dataResponse = new DataResponse();
   dataResponse.Data = reply.Data();
   handler.pushmessage( dataResponse );
   //return dataResponse;
}

//call this sub somewhere inside the idle cycle synchronized with the main thread
void proceedMessages() {
  while (!handler.empty())
  {
    DataResponse* dr = handler.popmessage();
    //do something with dr
    //free dr
  }
}
```